# Simple iOS app shows images in iOS Simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uitabbar

There's something very odd going on with my Xcode that causes images not to be displayed on a physical device, yet they are displayed in the simulator.

At first, I thought my own code was at fault - or something I did wrong with the project.

The steps below now show that even when I am creating a completely empty iOS based on one of the standard templates in Xcode 6, I still get the problem.

(Note: I'm running Xcode 6.0, although I had this problem with Xcode 5 just before upgrading (thinking it would fix it.  Secondly, I am not running a jailbroken iPhone).

Steps I did:

1. Created new project, based on the "Tabbed Application" template. [image: Chosen tabbed app template]
2. Changed deployment target to 7.1 so that it runs on my iPhone 5. [image: Deployment target changed]
3. Set device to iPhone 5 (simulator), and hit run.  The images that are bundled with the template are displayed (a circle and a square).
4. I now set the device to be my actual iPhone
5. I clean and run. This time, there are no images displayed at all.

See images below for how it looks in the iOS simulator, followed by a screenshot of how it looks on my iPhone.

I tried deleting various Xcode related cache files, but to no avail. Ideas?

[image: How it looks in the iOS Simulator]
[image: How it looks on my real iOS device]

Comment: Case matters in the name of the image. Make sure your code matches the actual filename.

Comment: I don't set any file name - I don't even write *any* code to be able to reproduce this problem. This is a code template that is included with Xcode 6.  Does it work on your side?